# How to disable HTTP request logs in Node/Express.js

Tags: node.js

I'm currently working on an application based on Node/Express.js.

I have a lot of different resources files (images, css, js...) that I don't want to be logged when executing my application...

**Exemple:** my node application logs:

```
GET /stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css 200 0ms
GET /js/lib/jquery-1.8.2.min.js 200 0ms
GET /stylesheets/bootstrap-responsive.2.1.1.min.css 200 0ms
GET /stylesheets/font-awesome.css 200 0ms
GET /stylesheets/bootstrapSwitch.css 200 0ms
GET /js/lib/jquery-ui-1.8.23.effects.min.js 200 0ms
GET /js/lib/knockout-2.1.0.js 200 0ms
GET /js/src/messages.manage.js 200 0ms
GET /js/lib/bootstrap.2.1.1.min.js 200 0ms
GET /js/lib/bootstrapSwitch.js 200 0ms
...
```

My question is:

Can I remove these logs based on the extension of a file ?
Example: *.js , *.css etc...

Comment: Move the logging pluggin below the resource pluggin in the app initialization. Done. Woohoo for Connect! Furthermore, please show your code, not your logs. ;)

Comment: I should have read the express.js documentation...
Thanks for the answer, it worked.

Comment: @ChristopherHarris please put this comment as an answer so that we can give you credit :)

Comment: Does Express.static really not have an option for that?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Move the logging pluggin below the resource pluggin in the app initialization. Done.

Woohoo for Connect!

Comment: Excellent, simply answer that works. To be more explicit: first `app.use(express.static` and after `app.use(logger('dev'));` or the one you are using

Comment: What would happen if I commented "app.use(logger('dev'));" totally ?

Answer (score 29):

On express.js 4,

comment: `//app.use(morgan('dev'));`

Comment: This is not a real solution: you remove also the logs about your URL calls. The right solution is the one from @Christopher

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable logs like
`POST /mydebug 200 1.380 ms - 2`
You must to use '**skip**' option in your **app.js** file:

Replace the line:

```
app.use(logger('dev');
```

With:

```
// only log error responses
app.use(logger('dev', {
    skip: function (req, res) { return res.statusCode < 400 }
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this helps

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (
    [
      ".css",
      ".js",
      ".jpg",
      ".jpeg",
      ".gif",
      ".ico",
      ".png",
      ".bmp",
      ".pict",
      ".csv",
      ".doc",
      ".pdf",
      ".pls",
      ".ppt",
      ".tif",
      ".tiff",
      ".eps",
      ".ejs",
      ".swf",
      ".midi",
      ".mid",
      ".ttf",
      ".eot",
      ".woff",
      ".woff2",
      ".otf",
      ".svg",
      ".svgz",
      ".webp",
      ".docx",
      ".xlsx",
      ".xls",
      ".pptx",
      ".ps",
      ".class",
      ".jar"
    ].indexOf(path.extname(req.path)) == -1
  ) {
    logger("dev")(req, res, next);
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In development, I prefer to know that the API endpoints are being hit, while ignoring the request for served files,

here's how I implemented it

```
if (config.env === 'development') {
  app.use(logger('dev', {
    skip(req, res) {
      return [
        '.css',
        '.js',
        '.jpg',
        '.jpeg',
        '.gif',
        '.ico',
        '.png',
        '.bmp',
        '.pict',
        '.csv',
        '.doc',
        '.pdf',
        '.pls',
        '.ppt',
        '.tif',
        '.tiff',
        '.eps',
        '.ejs',
        '.swf',
        '.midi',
        '.mid',
        '.ttf',
        '.eot',
        '.woff',
        '.woff2',
        '.otf',
        '.svg',
        '.svgz',
        '.webp',
        '.docx',
        '.xlsx',
        '.xls',
        '.pptx',
        '.ps',
        '.class',
        '.jar'
      ].indexOf(path.extname(req.path)) !== -1;
    }
  }));
}
```