# can't disable following express:* related pm2 logs?

Tags: node.js, express, pm2, pm2-logrotate

I want to disable some logs (express:router) from express code which use pm2 to run.
Current logs are as follows

```
GMT express:router dispatching GET /healthcheck
10|consumer  | Wed, 10 Oct 2018 19:40:04 GMT express:router query  : /healthcheck
10|consumer  | Wed, 10 Oct 2018 19:40:04 GMT express:router expressInit  : /healthcheck
10|consumer  | Wed, 10 Oct 2018 19:40:04 GMT express:router corsMiddleware  : /healthcheck
10|consumer  | Wed, 10 Oct 2018 19:40:04 GMT express:router jsonParser  : /healthcheck
10|consumer  | Wed, 10 Oct 2018 19:40:04 GMT body-parser:json skip empty body
10|consumer  | Wed, 10 Oct 2018 19:40:04 GMT express:router urlencodedParser  : /healthcheck
10|consumer  | Wed, 10 Oct 2018 19:40:04 GMT body-parser:urlencoded skip empty body
```

- I pass `/dev/null` to error_file or out_file to disable logs saving -
  not works i can still see the logs
- `Run pm2 using command - pm2 start consumer -o "/dev/null" -e "/dev/null"  - Not works.`
- I run it using `DEBUG=express.* node index.js` - not worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable HTTP request logs in Node/Express.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15952674/how-to-disable-http-request-logs-in-node-express-js)

Comment: @NishantGhodke no i want to keep it but i want to remove express:router query, express:router expressInit and other express middleware related logs

Comment: Well wait, `DEBUG=express.*` turns ON all logs. Please read morgan documentation.

Comment: @NishantGhodke yes i know that so i run without it also but didnt help ;(

Answer (score 0):

I manage to get it done by adding following environment var
process.env.DEBUG=false